# export after bash function definition

Tags: bash

I am writing my own functions that are sources from my `.bashrc`.  I fail to understand whether I should use `export -f curisac` after defining the function `curisac`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You do **not** need to export the function to use it in your open interactive shell.
- You do **not** need to export it if your interactive shells load `.bashrc` and the functions are defined there.
- But you **do** need to export the functions to have them available in shell processes that are started from your running interactive shell (without defining them in a file loaded at the start like `.bashrc`) by executing `sh` for example.

In short: no need if your shells load `.bashrc`.